# Unable to do searching using custom pipe created in angular 7

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, search

How can i search in angular 7 using pipe (like filter in angular 1) ? Below is the code which i tried.But that returns only if exact match is there. But i need results which contains that word.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'search',
  pure:true
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform { 
  transform(data: any,searchTxt:string): any {
    if(!data || !searchTxt)
    {
      return data;
    }   
    return data.filter(function(x) {
      return x.name ==searchTxt}) ;    
   }`
}
```

i tried below code also but doesn't work

```
return data.filter(x=>x.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexof(searchTxt.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
```

This throws error:  x.name.indexof is not a function

How can i do contains search using javascript\angular ?

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code. Besides, `indexof` should be `indexOf` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [**`indexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead of `===` or `indexof`(which I think is a typo in your code).

Plus you should not be using a `pipe` to filter values. Here's why Angular doesn't recommend using `pipe`s to filter or sort values.

> Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification. Both filter and orderBy require parameters that reference object properties. Read more about that [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

That being said, you can basically write the logic to filter data, right inside your Component:

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  users = [];
  filteredUsers = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .subscribe((users: any[]) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.filteredUsers = [...this.users];
      });
  }

  onSearchTextChange(searchString) {
    this.filteredUsers = [
      ...this.users.filter(user => user.name.indexOf(searchString) > -1)
    ];
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working CodeSandbox Sample**](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-filter-in-component-gev02) for your ref.